# Formerly Composite Numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence, primes

#### Sequence Definition

Construct a sequence of positive integers `a(n)` as follows:

1. `a(0) = 4`
2. Each term `a(n)`, other than the first, is the smallest number that satisfies the following:
   a) `a(n)` is a composite number,
   b) `a(n) > a(n-1)`, and
   c) `a(n) + a(k) + 1` is a composite number for each `0 <= k < n`.

So we start with `a(0) = 4`. The next entry, `a(1)` must be `9`. It can't be `5` or `7` since those aren't composite, and it can't be `6` or `8` because `6+4+1=11` is not composite and `8+4+1=13` is not composite. Finally, `9+4+1=14`, which is composite, so `a(1) = 9`.

The next entry, `a(2)` must be `10`, since it's the smallest number larger than `9` with `10+9+1=20` and `10+4+1=15` both composite.

For the next entry, `11` and `13` are both out because they're not composite. `12` is out because `12+4+1=17` which is not composite. `14` is out because `14+4+1=19` which is not composite. Thus, `15` is the next term of the sequence because `15` is composite and `15+4+1=20`, `15+9+1=25`, and `15+10+1=26` are all each composite, so `a(3) = 15`.

Here are the first 30 terms in this sequence:

```
4, 9, 10, 15, 16, 22, 28, 34, 35, 39, 40, 46, 52, 58, 64, 70, 75, 76, 82, 88, 94, 100, 106, 112, 118, 119, 124, 125, 130, 136
```

This is [OEIS A133764](http://oeis.org/A133764).

#### Challenge

Given an input integer `n`, output the `n`th term in this sequence.

#### Rules

- You can choose either 0- or 1-based indexing. Please state which in your submission.
- The input and output can be assumed to fit in your language's native integer type.
- The input and output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: **Title:** The number formerly known as composite.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn If this had something to do with art or music, I'd go with it. But, I'll stick with the title I currently have.

Comment: Was more of a joke ;).

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
!üȯṗ→+fotpN
```

1-indexed.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9odXNr/yBt4oKB4bijMzD/IcO8yK/huZfihpIrZm90cE7//w)

### Explanation

```
!üȯṗ→+fotpN  Implicit input, a number n.
          N  The list of positive integers [1,2,3,4,..
      f      Keep those
         p   whose list of prime factors
       ot    has a nonempty tail: [4,6,8,9,10,12,..
 ü           De-duplicate wrt this equality predicate:
     +       sum
    →        plus 1
  ȯṗ         is a prime number.
             Result is [4,9,10,15,16,..
!            Get n'th element.
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 83 bytes

1-indexed

```js
f=(n,a=[-1,p=4])=>a[n]||f(n,a.some(x=>(P=n=>n%--x?P(n):x<2)(x-=~p),p++)?a:[...a,p])
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(n,a=[-1,p=4])=>a[n]||f(n,a.some(x=>(P=n=>n%--x?P(n):x<2)(x-=~p),p++)?a:[...a,p])

for(n = 1; n <= 30; n++) {
  console.log('a(' + n + ') = ' + f(n))
}
```

#### Commented

Helper function **P()**, returning **true** if **n** is prime, or **false** otherwise:

```js
P = n => n % --x ? P(n) : x < 2
```

NB: It must be called with **x = n**.

Main function **f()**:

```js
f = (               // given:
  n,                //   n = target index
  a = [-1, p = 4]   //   a = computed sequence with an extra -1 at the beginning
) =>                //   p = last appended value
  a[n] ||           // if a[n] exists, stop recursion and return it
  f(                // otherwise, do a recursive call to f() with:
    n,              //   n unchanged
    a.some(x =>     //   for each value x in a[]:
      P(x -= ~p),   //     rule c: check whether x + p + 1 is prime
                    //     rule a: because a[0] = -1, this will first compute P(p)
      p++           //     rule b: increment p before the some() loop starts
    ) ?             //   end of some(); if truthy:
      a             //     p is invalid: use a[] unchanged
    :               //   else:
      [...a, p]     //     p is valid: append it to a[]
  )                 // end of recursive call
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 70 bytes

```perl6
{(4,->+_{first {none($^a X+0,|(_ X+1)).is-prime},_.tail^..*}...*)[$_]}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##NY3disIwEIXvfYq5kDVZ05C/phVZn2NBbCkaIYu20roLUvvs3RPBizlhvi@cuYX@4uffIdCfl8ft4vqgj2N3CvQ1j8yJbLeux3PshzuNbdcGtqwa@l4r8WQ1Xs25jEN26@M1TKKW9yZeKik/J4ng@2V9mOahedCr0apMbxfvlVVWcfnTxZatBK347ARtBGmFyTFekDGYUpCFsmAW3sE7uBwuh/NwBVgBX4CX4CX4xqWuVKZAtTYpyhTpiEnWpDM2fbH@Hw) 0-indexed

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter $_

  (  # generate the sequence

    4, # seed the sequence

    -> +_ { # pointy block that has a slurpy list parameter _ (all previous values)

      first

      {  # bare block with placeholder parameter $a

        none(                 # none junction
            $^a               # placeholder parameter for this inner block
          X+                
            0,                # make sure $a isn't prime
            |( _ X+ 1 )       # check all a(k)+1
        ).is-prime            # make sure none are prime
      },

      _.tail ^.. *            # start looking after the previous value
    }

    ...                       # keep generating values until

    *                         # never stop

  )[$_]                       # index into the sequence
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>112</s> 107 bytes

thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder) for a byte.

```python
n=-1,4;v=5
exec"while any(all((v-~k)%i for i in range(2,v))for k in n):v+=1\nn+=v,;v+=1\n"*input()
print~-v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcjBCsIwDADQ@74iDITEtYdNvWz0T7wUqS6sZKXU6C779crw9nhpK/MqQ63ibG@uk7pbE77h0X5mjgG8bOhjRFS7L3RieK4ZGFgge3kFHIwSHbccJzRq5/q7SOfUTH@3Z5b0LkhNyixlt1rr5Qc)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>115</s> 109 bytes

```python
n=-1,4;v=4;x=input()
while x:v+=1;k=1^any(all((v-~k)%i for i in range(2,v))for k in n);n+=(v,)*k;x-=k
print v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcgxDsMgDADAPa9gqWQ3MJBmKvJXKjGkjQVyUEQdsvTrVLnxylnXTabehZy3c1CaQyOW8q2Aw7FyXkx76kg@JPKvKCfEnAHU/RLe2Ly33bBhMXuUzwKTVcTr0nWCQUYCtXhPoTlKQ9lZqtHeH38)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 21 bytes

0-indexed

```
®4Iµ)˜D¤N‹sN+>p_P*iN¼
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P8wNWFiMWX//8KuNEnCtSnLnETCpE7igLlzTis@cF9QKmlOwrz//zY)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/),  <s>140</s>  138 bytes

*Thanks to @Jonathan Frech for saving two bytes!*

```c
c(n,i){for(i=1;++i<n;)i=n%i?i:n;i=i>n;}f(n){int s[n],k,j,i=0;for(*s=k=4;i++-n;i[s]=k)for(j=!++k;j-i;)2-c(k)-c(k-~s[j++])?j=!++k:f;n=n[s];}
```

0-indexed

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU7LDsIwDLvvK8qkSQ1tJV6nZWEfMnZARUVZRUAbt2n8@mjBBx/s2I53d@/X1WuxDHN4jpppj8ZwIwhMUnHLtSATnwWXoAVmlreaOulttINl2mFObSeKdEI2xqXrbuopQtYH2hgTcXCMcHBeR8jkPlM3GNND@/frgEKSUrisuf5xZdFQzIVKSDVKZzVvKW6OidOD8DMzXmNygy6r20VKq4JmACyW9Qs)

Comment: `++k,j=0` can twice be `j=!++k`, [138 bytes](https://tio.run/##JU7LDsIwDLvvK8qkSQ1tJV6nZWEfMnZARUVZRUAbt2n8@mjBBx/s2I53d@/X1WuxDHN4jpppj8ZwIwhMUnHLtSATnwWXoAVmlreaOulttINl2mFObSeKdEI2xqXrbuopQtYH2hgTcXCMcHBeR8jkPlM3GNND@/frgEKSUrisuf5xZdFQzIVKSDVKZzVvKW6OidOD8DMzXmNygy6r20VKq4JmACyW9Qs).

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) + `-rprime`, <s>85</s> 75 bytes

```ruby
->n{*a=x=4
n.times{x+=1;!x.prime?&&a.none?{|k|(x+k+1).prime?}?a<<x:redo}
x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcvRCoIwFIDhe59i3Yg2PCh1Vc49SHSxaIKIZ2MaHNn26p0iuvz5@MPrsfOouBkwHo0idS4QtmmxaySpuuuBwIdv6rI0gA6tjmlOFclZdvWfsjZ9T5dgny4XlNmLqgWAU1vDYnwUCZMYb3gXmd/Ob5PDlZvwez8)

A lambda returning the 0-indexed nth element.

-10 bytes: Use `redo` and a ternary operator instead of `loop`...`break` and a conditional chain

Ungolfed:

```ruby
->n{
  *a=x=4                         # x is the most recent value: 4
                                 # a is the list of values so far: [4]
  n.times{                       # Repeat n times:
    x += 1                       # Increment x
    !x.prime? &&                 # If x is composite, and
      a.none?{|k|(x+k+1).prime?} #   for all k, a(n)+x+1 is composite,
      ? a<<x                     # Add x to a
      : redo                     # Else, restart the block (go to x+=1)
  }
  x                              # Return the most recent value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 65 bytes

```
±0=-1;±1=4;±n_:=±(n-1)+1//.a_/;PrimeQ/@Array[a+1+±#&,n,0,Or]:>a+1
```

Uses CP-1252 (default Windows) encoding. 1-indexed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78///QRgNbXUPrQxsNbU2AZF68le2hjRp5uoaa2ob6@nqJ8frWAUWZuamB@g6ORUWJldGJ2obahzYqq@nk6Rjo@BfFWtkBRf5D5MDihgax@vpAPXkl/wE)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>186</s> 173 bytes

```java
n->{int a[]=new int[n+1],r=a[n]=4;a:for(;n>0;)if(c(++r)<2){for(int x:a)if(x>0&c(r-~x)>1)continue a;a[--n]=r;}return r;}int c(int n){for(int i=2;i<n;n=n%i++<1?0:n);return n;}
```

0-indexed.
Unfortunately prime-checks (or anti-prime/composite checks in this case) aren't that cheap in Java..

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##TVDBbsIwDL3zFRbSpkShpbCdCO2@YFw4Vj2EkG5h1KnSlIFQ9@udw9A2KXFiv@Q9@x3USSWuNXjYf4z6qLoOXpXF6wTAYjC@VtrAJqa3AmgWI3JJlYE2rQ0g5DBiUlwjpsoqR/MZX5coFtXM56rEKn@WalU7zyQWmeS2ZpoJ4fl6ya@xHL@eVyoC5yJ71MwnX2deLLh2GCz2BpRUZZIQk5eDN6H3CHSbSOpsPoeNC9AqH8DVEN4N7C7BJNr1GCb/@/7VsvlS2jVKzPHBCrFevGQrGutOjHIYAdp@d7QauqACHSdn99CQOWwbvMW3slL8x5joGDRkQpw7JuzmD8CfWEZiTxSE4DcEYHvpgmlS14e0JbrAmhRTapOL6Qymd4OH8Rs)

```java
n->{                     // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  int a[]=new int[n+1],  //  Integer-array of size `n+1`
      r=a[n]=4;          //  Start the result and last item at 4
  a:for(;n>0;)           //  Loop as long as `n` is larger than 0
    if(c(++r)<2){        //   Raise `r` by 1, and if it's a composite:
      for(int x:a)       //    Inner loop over the array
        if(x>0           //     If the item in the array is filled in (non-zero),
           &c(r-~x)>1)   //     and if `r+x+1` is a prime (not a composite number):
          continue a;}   //      Continue the outer loop
      a[--n]=r;}         //    Decrease `n` by 1, and put `r` in the array
  return r;}             //  Return the result

// Separated method to check if a given number is a composite number
// (It's a composite number if 0 or 1 is returned, otherwise it's a prime.)
int c(int n){for(int i=2;i<n;n=n%i++<1?0:n);return n;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 170 bytes

```c
P(n,d,b){for(b=d=n>1;++d<n;)b=b&&n%d;n=b;}h(n,N,b,k){if(!n)return 4;for(b=N=h(n-1);b;)for(b=k=!N++;k<n;b|=P(h(k++)-~N));n=N;}f(n,j){for(j=0;n--;)if(P(h(++j)))j++;n=h(j);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BDoIwEEXXcgohgXTSNgHjbqgHYNFwBUutUuJoCK4Qr45D2P68936n7123rq0g5ZWDObxG4Yw3dKlQSl8TgjOuKCj3SMbh8mDSKqcGmPsgUoLxNn1GOp5xV61hQleADmFfBpNaKXHglvuaVjzEICXonwXgpMUlcDLu19GUSFojcHsjpYwAEFkn7kbAZX1eexINzMlhExoWmvpU4nvsaQoiy73KVBANX3A/WdY/)